# .net Core EF - Dynamically Add to DbSet by string name or type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have a thousand classes that all inherit one base class, and each of these classes (not the base) has a table, each of which has the same required columns.  How can I use reflection or generics to add or update a row in the correct table?  I'll know the name of the specific entity at runtime.

There are a handful of stackoverflow posts about getting a dbset with reflection, but the answer results in an IQueryable, which you cannot add a new item to.  Those posters seem content with that because they're just fetching data I suppose.  I need a DbSet so I can add and update.  I can get the fully qualified entity name and type, but how do I get a DbSet with that?  I don't want to write a 1000 line switch statement :(

Comment: How about dynamic SQL, using reflection to build the query? `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using magic strings to add all the properties I knew would be present in the base class.  Although not ideal, it did add to the correct table which was the ultimate goal.

```
            var entityType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseTypeEntity)).GetType(namespacePrefix + typeName);

            // create an instance of that type
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);

            // Get a property on the type that is stored in the 
            // property string
            PropertyInfo prop = entityType.GetProperty("Active");
            prop.SetValue(instance, true, null);
            // .... more properties

            _context.Add(instance);
```

Comment: BaseTypeEntity is what?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by dynamically creating a new type that inherits from DbContext and the use Reflection Emit to add the DbSets to this type.

It's a bit of a long solution to try and post into a response here, but here's a GitHub link to a working demo of how it can be done - [EF Core Dynamic Db Context](https://github.com/rschreiber/EFCoreDynamic)

Comment: The only place I see entities being added to a set is in the Program.cs where this is: dynDbContext.Add<Pet>(new Pet() {Name = "Daisy"});  But I won't know the type at compile time, so how does this example fit the problem?  I would need something more like dbContext.Add<"Pet">  or dbContext.Add<typeof("namespace.pet")>

Comment: You don't need to use the generic version of add. You can use dynDbContext.Add (myObject).